# acro's \printacronyms fails for nested acronyms if inserted thanks to the \AtEndDocument hook

Tags: acro, hooks

In the following MCE example, the `acro`'s list of the acronyms `\printacronyms` is inserted, not in the document body, but in the preamble thanks to the hook `\AtEndDocument` and that works like a charm:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\AtEndDocument{\printacronyms}
\DeclareAcronym{gnu}{
  short = GNU ,
  long = GNU's Not Unix
}
\begin{document}
\ac{gnu}.
\end{document}
```

In the following MCE example, the “GPL” acronym is defined in terms of the other acronym   “GNU” and that works like a charm:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{gnu}{
  short = GNU ,
  long = GNU's Not Unix
}
\DeclareAcronym{gpl}{
  short = GPL ,
  long = \acs{gnu} General Public License
}
\begin{document}
\ac{gpl}.
\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

But, if these two examples are merged:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\AtEndDocument{\printacronyms}
\DeclareAcronym{gnu}{
  short = GNU ,
  long = GNU's Not Unix
}
\DeclareAcronym{gpl}{
  short = GPL ,
  long = \acs{gnu} General Public License
}
\begin{document}
\ac{gpl}.
\end{document}
```

the compilation fails with the error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \l__acro_pages_list_display_bool 
l.17 \end{document}
```

Note that the problem does not arise with the `\AtBeginDocument` hook.

Do you understand what's going on and how to make this last example work?

Comment: It probably can't work without a change in acro. The problem is imho (but I checked only a bit) that acro uses the enddocument inside \printacronyms too and as it is a one-time hooks that messes up the code order.

Comment: Attention of the `acro`'s author [drawn](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/254).

Answer (score 6):

if you use `\ShowHook{enddocument}` in your example you can see that acro uses the hook too. Sadly it is even used inside `\printacronyms`, and as it is a one-time hook moving `\printacronyms` inside this hook messes up the code order.
I only managed to avoid the error by changing a acro command and moving its code to a later hook. This is not meant as a general solution only as a demonstration that the hook matters! The redefinition could mess up the code in other places:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\AtEndDocument{\printacronyms}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \acro_record_page:n #1
  {
    \__acro_record_page:n {#1}
    \hook_gput_code:nnn {enddocument/afterlastpage} {acro} %moved from endocument
      {
        \seq_gremove_duplicates:c {g__acro_#1_pages_seq}
        \acro_property_set:nnx {#1} {pages}
          { \seq_use:cn {g__acro_#1_pages_seq} {|} }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\DeclareAcronym{gnu}{
  short = GNU ,
  long = GNU's Not Unix
}
\DeclareAcronym{gpl}{
  short = GPL ,
  long = \acs{gnu} General Public License
}
\begin{document}
\ac{gpl}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAICS, the compilation of your example fails as well, with the same error, so `\DeclareHookRule{enddocument}{acro}{after}{denis}` doesn't the trick. Am I missing something?

Comment: It worked for me. Did you add the label to the AddToHook?

Comment: I just copied-pasted your example. About `\AddToHook`, do you mean `\AtEndDocument[denis]{\printacronyms}`? If so, yes, and the same happens with `\AddToHook{enddocument}[denis]{\printacronyms}`.

Comment: well that is curious. I started with "mylabel" as label, and that works, but then changed here for you to "denis" and that fails. I need to investigate ;-)

Comment: I am cursed! ;)

Comment: it is perhaps a "second compilation effect" ;-)